# Reording the variables and the legend a in a (pseudo) dumbbell plot based on groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse

I have created the following plot [image]

using the following code:

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(x=percentage, y=metric, color=category)) + 
  geom_line(color="gray", size=1.75) +
  geom_point(size=2) + scale_color_viridis(discrete = T) + 
  geom_text(aes(label=glue("{percentage}%"), x=bump_percentage), color = "dimgray", size=3) +
  theme_fivethirtyeight() + theme(legend.title=element_blank())
```

I can provide details and a reproducible data frame if need be, but I am hoping that my problem is simple enough that it won't be necessary. Essentially, I am working with four variables:

"category": boosted incomes, child survival, etc
"metric": the long strings on the y axis
"round": either "baseline" or "endline"
"percentage": the x-axis

MY PROBLEM: I want the values on my y axis to be ordered by "category", starting with the "food security" variables, followed by "child survival", "boosted incomes", and "empowered churches". Ideally, my legend would also appear in this order.

I tried simply putting something like
`mydata %>% arrange(category)`
before my ggplot, which appeared to order the data correctly, but then when I called it into the ggplot I got the same graph.

If you think you can solve this but need me to create the data frame, I am happy to, but I'm importing it, so it would be a little cumbersome. Here is a screenshot:
[image]

output of `dput(my data)` is:

```
structure(list(category = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("food security", 
"child survival", "boosted incomes", "empowered churches"), class = "factor"), 
    metric = c("Low income is not a \"serious problem\"", "At least one stable income source", 
    "Low income is not a \"serious problem\"", "At least one stable income source", 
    "Poor health is not a \"serious problem\"", "No children sent to work in the city", 
    "Poor health is not a \"serious problem\"", "No children sent to work in the city", 
    "Spiritual support is not a \"serious problem\"", "Women who feel hope for the future", 
    "Spiritual support is not a \"serious problem\"", "Women who feel hope for the future", 
    "Never going to bed hungry", "Children at a healthy weight", 
    "Never going to bed hungry", "Children at a healthy weight"
    ), round = c("baseline", "baseline", "endline", "endline", 
    "baseline", "baseline", "endline", "endline", "baseline", 
    "baseline", "endline", "endline", "baseline", "baseline", 
    "endline", "endline"), percentage = c(75, 72, 93, 94, 80, 
    80, 95, 96, 75, 53, 97, 84, 53, 79, 98, 93), bump_percentage = c(72, 
    69, 96, 97, 77, 77, 98, 99, 72, 50, 100, 87, 50, 76, 101, 
    96)), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: `ggplot` plots character variables only after converting them to factor variables. By default, these are ordered alphabetically. Try `mydata %>% arrange(category) %>% mutate(category = factor(category, c("food security", "child survival", "boosted incomes", "empowered churches")))` and plot again

Comment: @AllanCameron, great thought, but no luck... perhaps I need to work a reorder() call into my "y =" statement within the initial ggplot function? I see how you converted categories to a factor, which seems to be headed in the right direction. In fact, if I print the data after running your code, the rows are in the perfect order. But when I run the same ggplot code, it spits out the same graph with the seemingly random ordering on the y axis.

Comment: @AllanCameron CORRECTION: it is not the *exact* same graph. The legend at the bottom does appropriately reorder! The y-axis, however, does not.

Comment: In that case could you post the output of `dput(mydata)` into a code block in your question? I will certainly be able to give you working code if you do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do grouped categorical variables is to use facets:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

ggplot(mydata, aes(x = percentage, y = metric, color = category)) + 
  geom_line(color = "gray", size = 1.75) +
  geom_point(size = 2) + 
  scale_color_viridis_d() + 
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(percentage, "%"), x = percentage), 
            color = "dimgray", size = 3, nudge_y = 0.2) +
  facet_grid(category ~ ., scales = "free_y", switch = "y") +
  theme_fivethirtyeight() + 
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  theme(strip.placement = "outside",
        panel.spacing.y = unit(0, "mm"),
        strip.text = element_text(face = 2),
        legend.justification = 1.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent! Also I didn't know about that nudge_y argument if I wanted to put the percentages above the points rather than beside. One other quick Q which you might know the answer to: is there any way I can get that legend centered below the whole plot rather than just the chart itself? Essentially move it over to the left a bit.

Comment: I tried doing it manually through legend.position, but I couldn't get that to work right.

Comment: @bricevk try `legend.justification = 1.5` inside `theme`. You might need to tweak this a bit depending on the size of your plotting device. I have updated my answer to illustrate.